# Why when extracting products data shows me that they are duplicate?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

When using bs4 the products show me that they are frequent despite all attempts to know solving this problem. I have failed to inform me to solve this problem and where is it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest


page = 'https://niceonesa.com/ar/'

headers = {
    'User-Argent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Viewer/97.9.3678.79'
}

productlink =[]
titles = []
brands=[]
prices=[]
offers = []
rates =[]
rate_starts=[]

for x in range(1,2):
    r= requests.get(f'https://niceonesa.com/ar/appcomponent--best-sales/?page={x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

    productlist = soup.find_all('div' , class_='product-container bg-white rounded-lg')



    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a',href= True):
            productlink.append(page + link ['href'])

    # testlink = 'https://niceonesa.com/ar/gifts/travel-size/ola-hair-mini-straightener-brush-n-215-n16250/'
    for link in productlink:
        r = requests.get(link , headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

        try:
            title  =soup.find('h1',class_='title').text.strip()
            titles.append(title)
            print(title)


        except:
            title='non'




        try:
            price = soup.find('h3',class_='preReductionPrice mb-2').text.strip()
            prices.append(price)

        except:
            price = 'non'
        try:
            offer = soup.find('h3',class_='sellingPrice text-nowrap')
            offers.append(offer)
        except:
            offer='non'
        try:
            rate = soup.find('span',class_='num-rating align-review').text.strip()
            rates.append(rate)

        except:
            rate = 'non'
        try:
            rate_start =soup.find('div', class_='num-rating start').text.strip()
            rate_starts.append(rate_start)
        except:
            rate_start = 'non'

    brand = productlist.find_all('h3', class_='brand-product mb-1')
    for i in range(len(brand)):
        brands.append(brand[i].text)
        filelist = ([titles, brands, prices, rates, rate_starts, productlink])
        exported = zip_longest(*filelist)
        with open('oo.csv', 'w' , encoding ='utf-8-sig' , newline='') as filecsv:
            wr = csv.writer(filecsv)
            wr.writerow(['title','brands','price','offer','rate','rate_starts','productlink'])
            wr.writerows(exported)
```

Thank you

I tried all possible solutions by searching on the Internet for the problem, but I did not find a way, and I could not understand the problem.

Comment: Please add more details about the specific problem and the desired behavior.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  What are you expecting to see vs what are you actually seeing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```py
>     for i in range(len(brand)):
>         brands.append(brand[i].text)
>         filelist = ([titles, brands, prices, rates, rate_starts, productlink])
>         exported = zip_longest(*filelist)
>         with open('oo.csv', 'w' , encoding ='utf-8-sig' , newline='') as filecsv:
>             wr = csv.writer(filecsv)
>             wr.writerow(['title','brands','price','offer','rate','rate_starts','productlink'])
>             wr.writerows(exported)
> ```

Why are you saving in the the loop? the only thing that should be in that loop is `brands.append(brand[i].text)` - you're copying all the products all over again for every brand. That's most likely the reason for the duplicates; but there are several other issues with your method...

---

> ```py
>         except: title='non'
> ```
>
> ```py
>         except: price = 'non'
> ```
>
> ```py
>         except: offer='non'
> ```
>
> ```py
>         except: rate = 'non'
> ```
>
> ```py
>         except: rate_start = 'non'
> ```

You should be appending in except too, otherwise you'll have uneven and misaligned columns (like say product1 had no offer but product2 did. but you didn't append anything for product1's offer so product2's offer will be the first offer in the list. then when you form the DataFrame, it'll look like product1 had that offer since it will be in the first row, and so on.)

---

> ```py
>     brand = productlist.find_all('h3', class_='brand-product mb-1')
>     for i in range(len(brand)):
>         brands.append(brand[i].text)
> ```

You can just do `brands = [brand.text for brand in productlist.find_all('h3', class_='brand-product mb-1')]` instead of appending on a loop, but it would be better if you had a surer way to make sure that the links and brands aligned perfectly - why don't you just get it in the *`for link in productlink...`* loop?

```py
    # for link in productlink:
        # r = requests.get(link , headers=headers)
        # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

        # brand = soup.find(lambda t: t.name=='a' and t.parent.name=='h2')`)
        brand = soup.select_one('h2>a')
        brands.append(brand.text.strip() if brand else 'non')
```

Comment: All those `except`s are bare, too. Anything could trigger them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use api on this site

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


result = []

for page in range(1, 3):
    url = f"https://api.niceonesa.com/?route=rest/product_admin/products&seo_url=appcomponent--best-sales&page={page}&sort=most_popular&limit=60&first=false"
    headers = {
        'authority': 'api.niceonesa.com',
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'platform': 'web',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    for product in response.json()['data']['products']:
        result.append({
            'link': product['share_url'],
            'title': product['en_name'],
            'brand': product['manufacturer'],
            'price': product['price_formated'],
            'offer': product['price'],
            'rate': product['total_reviews'],
            'rate_starts': product['rating'],
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

DF OUTPUT:

```
                                                                                                                                 link                                                                            title                brand         price   offer  rate  rate_starts
0                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/gifts/travel-size/ola-hair-mini-straightener-brush-n-215-n16250/                                         Ola Hair Mini Straightener Brush - N-215             Ola Hair  160.43 ريال   128.34  1730          4.9
1        https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/face-moisturizer/bodyblendz-vitamin-c-hyaluronic-acid-penetrating-serum-30ml-n18420/                    BodyBlendz Vitamin C Hyaluronic Acid Penetrating Serum - 30ml          Body Blendz      65 ريال    65.00   243          5.0
2                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/mascara/essence-lash-princess-false-lash-effect-mascara-black-n6722/                          Essence Lash Princess False Lash Effect Mascara - Black              essence   25.30 ريال    18.40  3272          5.0
3      https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/tools-and-accessories/feather-flamingo-s-for-shaving-facial-body-hair-3-pieces-n12850/                       Feather-Flamingo S For Shaving Facial Body Hair - 3 Pieces     Feather-Flamingo   17.53 ريال    13.00  1252          5.0
4                                https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/mascara/essence-i-love-extreme-crazy-volume-mascara-black-n452/                              Essence I Love Extreme Crazy Volume Mascara - Black              essence   20.70 ريال    18.00  2979          4.9
5                              https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/lips/liquid-lipstick/etude-house-dear-darling-water-tint-cherry-n2826/                                     Etude House Dear Darling Water Tint - Cherry          Etude House   30.67 ريال    17.83  2163          4.9
6                                            https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/eyeliner/thebalm-schwing-liquid-eyeliner-black-n34/                                          theBalm Schwing Liquid Eyeliner - Black    theBalm Cosmetics   63.25 ريال    29.00  2613          4.9
7                                  https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/mascara/bourjois-twist-up-the-volume-mascara-ultra-black-n67/                               Bourjois Twist Up The Volume Mascara - Ultra Black             Bourjois   44.85 ريال    33.00  2868          4.9
8                              https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/eyeliner/rimmel-london-scandaleyes-waterproof-eyeliner-nude-n320/                             Rimmel London Scandaleyes Waterproof Eyeliner - Nude        Rimmel London   32.20 ريال    19.55  1797          5.0
9                                    https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/eyeliner/mahmood-saeed-elizabeth-helen-eyeliner-black-n503/                                   Mahmood Saeed Elizabeth Helen Eyeliner - Black        Mahmood Saeed   19.55 ريال    18.96  1192          5.0
10                                   https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyebrow/eyebrow-mascara/essence-lash-and-brow-gel-mascara-n1561/                                                Essence Lash and Brow Gel Mascara              essence   32.20 ريال    16.10  1384          4.9
11  https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/face/makeup-removers/garnier-skin-active-micellar-cleansing-water-for-sensitive-skin-400ml-n3378/          Garnier Skin Active Micellar Cleansing Water For Sensitive Skin - 400ml              Garnier      29 ريال    25.05   951          5.0
12                            https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/face/makeup-spray/topface-fix-quickly-makeup-setting-spray-100ml-n8394/                                 Topface Fix Quickly Makeup Setting Spray - 100ml              Topface   35.02 ريال    35.02   763          4.9
13                                       https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/face/face-primer/maybelline-baby-skin-instant-pore-22ml-n44/                                         Maybelline Baby Skin Instant Pore - 22ml           Maybelline   51.75 ريال    37.38  1406          4.9
14                                       https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/brushes-amp-tools/face-brushes/marble-angled-brush-m1-n5596/                                                         Marble Angled Brush - M1               MARBLE   65.71 ريال    59.34   941          4.9
15                                         https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/tools-and-accessories/derma-roller-4-in-1-kit-n80/                                                          Derma roller 4 in 1 Kit  Derma roller System  149.50 ريال    36.80  1000          4.9
16                                    https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/face/bb-amp-cc-cream/missha-m-perfect-cover-bb-cream-no-27-n69/                                          Missha M Perfect Cover BB Cream - No.27               Missha   79.35 ريال    44.85  1158          4.9
17                                     https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/eyeshadow/revolution-reloaded-palette-iconic-fever-n9234/                                       Revolution Reloaded Palette - Iconic Fever           Revolution      65 ريال    42.25  1158          5.0
18                                     https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/lip-care/carmex-classic-lip-balm-medicated-10g-n13459/                                          Carmex Classic Lip Balm Medicated - 10g               Carmex   19.55 ريال    15.64   698          5.0
19                                             https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/lips/lip-liner/topface-waterproof-lipliner-110-n17038/                                               Topface Waterproof Lipliner - 110               Topface      25 ريال    25.00   120          4.9
20                        https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/hair-care/oil-amp-masks/nature-repeat-aloe-vera-92-soothing-gel-300ml-n11782/                                 Nature Repeat Aloe Vera 92% Soothing Gel - 300ml        Nature Repeat      20 ريال    18.00   741          4.9
21                                https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/eye-care/the-ordinary-caffeine-solution-5-egcg-30ml-n11906/                                  The Ordinary Caffeine Solution 5% + EGCG - 30ml         The Ordinary   66.81 ريال    60.95   448          4.9
22                                       https://niceonesa.com/ar/gifts/men-gift-sets/blanco-musk-set-eau-de-perfume-4-pieces-n15556/                                      Blanco Musk Set - Eau De Perfume - 4 Pieces               BLANCO  366.85 ريال   199.00   705          4.9
23                               https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/eyeliner/jockey-eyeliner-unique-and-soft-intensive-black-n5512/                                Jockey Eyeliner Unique and Soft - Intensive Black              Jockey    21.85 ريال    18.40   744          5.0
24                                         https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/jose-eber-pro-series-curling-iron-25mm-n522/                                         Jose Eber Pro Series curling iron - 25mm            jose eber     253 ريال   127.01   742          4.9
25             https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/tools-and-accessories/derma-roller-system-derma-roller-for-skin-0-50mm-n11109/                               Derma Roller System Derma Roller for skin - 0.50mm  Derma roller System   31.76 ريال    24.46   131          4.9
26                         https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/lips/liquid-lipstick/etude-house-dear-darling-water-tint-strawberry-n2824/                                 Etude House Dear Darling Water Tint - Strawberry          Etude House      31 ريال    16.50   334          4.9
27               https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/highlighter/powder-highlighter/revolution-ultra-blush-palette-sugar-and-spice-n7846/                                 Revolution Ultra Blush Palette - Sugar and Spice           Revolution      96 ريال    62.40   768          5.0
28                                             https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/mascara/topface-focus-point-volume-mascara-n8341/                                               Topface Focus Point Volume Mascara              Topface   30.19 ريال    28.00   485          5.0
29                                 https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/face/powder/topface-instyle-loose-powder-banana-smart-shade-n8356/                                Topface Instyle Loose Powder - Banana Smart Shade              Topface   71.30 ريال    58.00   925          5.0
30                                    https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/jose-eber-wet-or-dry-styling-iron-1-5-inch-n7910/                                     Jose Eber Wet Or Dry Styling Iron - 1.5 inch            jose eber  228.85 ريال   128.00   152          4.9
31                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/okema-1200-shift-hair-styler-ok2118-n3732/                                            Okema 1200 Shift Hair Styler - OK2118                Okema  171.35 ريال   154.10   431          4.9
32                                  https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/face/foundation/m-asam-magic-finish-makeup-foundation-30ml-n8181/                                    M. Asam Magic Finish Makeup Foundation - 30ml              M. Asam  126.50 ريال   120.18   547          4.7
33        https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/lips/lip-sets/thebalm-meet-matte-hughes-set-of-6-mini-lipsticks-limited-edition-vol2-n1750/         theBalm Meet Matte Hughes Set of 6 Mini Lipsticks Limited Edition - Vol2    theBalm Cosmetics  148.35 ريال    75.00  1303          4.9
34                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/highlighter/palette-amp-set/ofra-pro-palette-soul-n11717/                                                          OFRA Pro Palette - Soul                OFRA   262.86 ريال   227.00   232          4.9
35                                                   https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/okema-4000-hair-dryer-ok882-n3723/                                                    Okema 4000 Hair Dryer - OK882                Okema  212.75 ريال   172.50    93          5.0
36                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-053-n10050/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 053              Topface   18.40 ريال     5.50    37          4.9
37                                         https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/jose-eber-pro-series-curling-iron-19mm-n258/                                         Jose Eber Pro Series Curling Iron - 19mm            jose eber     253 ريال   127.01   263          4.9
38                                                       https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/okema-hair-styler-ok977-n2928/                                                        Okema Hair Styler - OK977                Okema  136.85 ريال   113.85    45          4.6
39                                               https://niceonesa.com/ar/perfume/musk/blanco-musk-special-eau-de-perfum-50ml-n16233/                                         Blanco Musk Special- Eau de Perfum- 50ml               BLANCO     147 ريال    75.00   104          4.9
40                            https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/brushes-amp-tools/sponges-amp-tools/ksd-puff-facial-powder-sponge-n330/                                                    KSD Puff Facial Powder Sponge                  KSD   32.20 ريال    20.70   454          4.9
41                                 https://niceonesa.com/ar/perfume/home-scents/oud-amp-bakhoor/nice-one-morouke-mini-1-ounce-n15086/                                                  Nice One Morouke Mini - 1 Ounce              Niceone  172.50 ريال   117.00   464          4.9
42                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-079-n8401/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 079              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   135          4.9
43                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-020-n10047/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 020              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   123          4.9
44                                                https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/okema-shift-hair-styler-ok2113-n3713/                                                 Okema Shift Hair Styler - OK2113                Okema  132.25 ريال   121.33    68          4.8
45                https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/brushes-amp-tools/brush-sets/bh-cosmetics-pink-perfection-brush-set-10-piece-n3161/                               BH Cosmetics Pink Perfection Brush Set - 10 Piece          BH cosmetics  102.35 ريال    68.00   373          4.9
46                                https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/jose-eber-100-ceramic-flat-iron-1-25-inch-pink-n1508/                              Jose Eber 100% Ceramic Flat Iron - 1.25 Inch - Pink            jose eber  287.50 ريال   179.00   312          4.9
47                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-002-n8406/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 002              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   139          4.9
48                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/jose-eber-clipless-curling-iron-32mm-n3286/                                           Jose Eber Clipless Curling Iron - 32mm            jose eber     253 ريال   156.98    80          4.9
49                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-061-n8396/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 061              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   138          5.0
50                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-024-n10045/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 024              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   164          5.0
51                                                 https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/lips/lipstick/mood-matcher-lipstick-yellow-n16681/                                                   Mood Matcher Lipstick - Yellow         Mood Matcher   40.94 ريال    40.94    59          5.0
52                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-047-n8384/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 047              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00    63          4.9
53                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-040-n10035/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 040              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   114          5.0
54                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-037-n8347/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 037              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00    96          5.0
55                                     https://niceonesa.com/ar/perfume/oud-perfume/blanco-royal-dehn-oud-mukhallat-half-tola-n15900/                                      Blanco Royal Dehn Oud mukhallat - Half Tola               BLANCO     294 ريال   151.00    92          5.0
56                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-010-n8400/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 010              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   243          5.0
57                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-018-n8547/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 018              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00    66          5.0
58                                                  https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/okema-4000-hair-dryer-ok1070-n3716/                                                   Okema 4000 Hair Dryer - OK1070                Okema  218.50 ريال   177.10    56          4.8
59                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-045-n8383/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 045              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00    81          4.9
60                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/jose-eber-clipless-curling-iron-13mm-pink-amp-black-n7466/                            Jose Eber Clipless Curling Iron - 13mm - Pink & Black            jose eber  217.35 ريال   172.50    19          4.5
61                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-care/kinetics-nano-shark-green-efficient-nail-treatment-15ml-n16122/                        Kinetics Nano Shark Green Efficient Nail Treatment - 15ml             kinetics   80.50 ريال    32.99    55          4.8
62                                   https://niceonesa.com/ar/perfume/perfume-offers/guerlain-santal-royal-125ml-eau-de-parfum-n1522/                                    Guerlain Santal Royal - 125ml - Eau De Parfum             Guerlain  688.85 ريال   688.85   240          4.9
63                                  https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/tools-and-accessories/gemstone-facial-roller-pink-n16252/                                                    Gemstone Facial Roller - Pink              Niceone   92.98 ريال    42.00    61          5.0
64                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-034-n8376/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 034              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   108          5.0
65                               https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/hair-care/oil-amp-masks/now-solutions-liquid-coconut-oil-118ml-n13158/                                         Now Solutions Liquid Coconut Oil - 118ml                 now    56.95 ريال    39.00    25          4.8
66                                      https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/facial-devices/sonata-9-in-1-electric-beauty-clean-set-n382/                                          Sonata 9 in 1 Electric Beauty Clean Set              Sonata      138 ريال   110.40    22          4.5
67                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-014-n8552/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 014              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   143          5.0
68                                     https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/tools-and-accessories/5in1-derma-roller-system-n15441/                                                        5In1 Derma Roller System   Derma roller System      69 ريال    62.10     2          5.0
69                                          https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-057-n10042/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 057              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00    45          4.9
70                                   https://niceonesa.com/ar/devices/hair-devices/joy-professional-multi-function-hair-dryer-n17172/                                       Joy Professional Multi Function Hair Dryer                  Joy     390 ريال   390.00     6          4.8
71        https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/sunscreen/cetaphil-tinted-sun-50spf-very-high-protection-face-fluid-light-medium-50ml-n17068/  Cetaphil Tinted Sun 50SPF Very High Protection Face Fluid - Light Medium - 50ml             Cetaphil  167.90 ريال   125.93     2          5.0
72                                 https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/eyes/mascara/topface-instyle-rich-curl-mascara-extra-black-n13929/                                 Topface Instyle Rich Curl Mascara - Extra Black               Topface   35.02 ريال    32.00     2          5.0
73                            https://niceonesa.com/ar/perfume/home-scents/incense-holders/usb-incense-burner-dark-gray-n-231-n17439/                                           USB Incense Burner - Dark Gray - N-231              Niceone  156.98 ريال    49.00    52          4.6
74                                https://niceonesa.com/ar/makeup/cheek/blush/thebalm-instain-powder-staining-blush-swiss-dot-n16772/                                theBalm Instain Powder Staining Blush - Swiss Dot    theBalm Cosmetics   64.40 ريال    49.00   158          5.0
75                                           https://niceonesa.com/ar/nails/nails-polish/topface-lasting-color-nail-enamel-033-n8362/                                          Topface Lasting Color Nail Enamel - 033              Topface   18.40 ريال    15.00   169          5.0
76                                    https://niceonesa.com/ar/care/face-care/tools-and-accessories/stella-derma-roller-system-n1479/                                                       Stella Derma Roller System  Derma roller System   67.85 ر
```

Comment: and to save use - `df.to_csv('name_or_path.csv')`